# Volume calculations using raster surface volume are too high

Tags: raster, dem, volume

I am looking to calculate the amount of water stored on a wetland behind a sluice. I have used clipped 1m DEM data to calculate the volumes using the raster surface volume tool (calculating volume below the base level, the base level is set at the level of the sluice).

I then repeated the process at 5 cm intervals representing different heights of the sluice. The problem I have is that the volumes look too high. I've checked the area (m2) and those are correct - is there any reason why the volumes might be bigger than expected?

To give an indication of scale, over a 50 cm rise in water levels I'm getting results of 10,000 cubic metres but am expecting results closer to 2,500 cubic metres.

Comment: Maybe you can include screenshots of the input parameters to your tool.  Are you using ArcGIS Surface Volumes?  Something else?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm using the raster surface volume tool in QGIS. However, I've just also had a third party check my back-of-the-envelope calculations and I have a feeling this might be human error rather than GIS error!